# 'str' object has no attribute 'get' -Learn Python The Hard Way EX39

Tags: python

I am a python beginner. I try to write my hometown city with dictionary after practicing ex39 of Learn Python The Hard Way.

Here are what I wrote:

```
    states = {
    'Orangon': 'OR',
    'Florida': 'FL',
    'California': 'CA',
    'New York': 'NY',
    'Michigan': 'MI',
}

for state, abbrev in states.items():
    print "%s is abbreviated %s" % (state, abbrev)

print states.get('Florida')
print states.get('California')


cities = {
    'New Taipei': 'NTP',
    'Taipei': 'TP',
    'Kaohsiung': 'KHU',
    'Taichung': 'TAC',
    'Taoyuan': 'TYN',
    'Tainan': 'TNA',
    'Hsinchu': 'HSC',
    'Keelung': 'KLG',
    'Chiayi': 'CYI',
    'Changhua': 'CHA',
    'Pingtung': 'PTG',
    'Zhubei': 'ZBI',
    'Yuanlin': 'Yln',
    'Douliu': 'Dlu',
    'Taitung': 'TAT',
    'Hualien': 'HUl',
    'Toufen': 'TFE',
    'Yilan': 'Yln',
    'Miaoli': 'Mli',
    'Magong': 'Mgn',
}

for cities, abbrev in cities.items():
    print "%s is %s" % (cities, abbrev)

print cities.get('Magong')
```

There is error in the last code:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ex39.2.py", line 27, in 
    print cities.get('Magong')
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'get'

I don't understand why there is no error in `print states.get('California')` but there is error in `print cities.get('Magong')`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your for loop you are assigning a string to the variable `cities`:

```
for cities, abbrev in cities.items():
    print "%s is %s" % (cities, abbrev)
```

thus, after the for loop, `cities` is no longer a dict, but a string.

Solution: use a different variable in your loop:

```
for city, abbrev in cities.items():
    print "%s is %s" % (city, abbrev)
```

Comment: I got it. Thank :)